# Two CLLocationManager interfere

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I have two CLLocationManage within an app. The first one is to monitor the beacon regions , while the other is to monitor the normal CLRegion.

First one in A.m

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

Second one in B.m

```
  gpsLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  gpsLocationManager.delegate = self;
```

I am pretty much sure for the latter, I have not called any startMonitoringForRegion on any beacon region. However, it seems the gpsLocationmanager in B keeps receiving the enterRegion callback from the the one in A. So it ends up with my checking the passed-in region para type to make the gpsLocationManager not respond to any callback from beacon region enter.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
  NSLog(@"%d regions under monitor:", self.gpsLocationManager.monitoredRegions.count);
  NSLog(@"%d regions in regionArray:", self.regionArray.count);
  NSLog(@"Region type %@:", [region class]);
 if(![region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]){
```

Any idea?

Regards
Hammer

Comment: Would a singleton help in this case? A static instance of the location manager which exist for the duration of the app running. That way you have only 1 location manager. Otherwise, maybe you can have a boolean flag to identify whether it should respond to location update.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to use singleton. However, as my monitoring is on different categories, which are set to be different accurancy, frequency, even the region types here. I change back the two CLLocationmanager approach at the end. Yes, your solution is good to go, however, just a bit curious why the issue reported happens, as I am using two different instances.

Answer (score 2):

`CoreLocation` functionality is provided on an app-wide basis.

This is why the common pattern is to initialize your `CLLocationManager` in your `AppDelegate` and make it the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

If you need to access your one `CLLocationManager` in multiple `UIViewController`s, I would make it a property of your `AppDelegate`.  You can then forward the callbacks you need to the `UIViewController`s if they have been initialized and are visible.

Comment: The problem for me is that I have different types of regions. Some regions I need normal update with good accuracy like kCLLocationAccuracyBest, while some need significant change update with accuracy like kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer etc. For this scenario, it is hard to make all into one location manager.

Comment: Today i tried again and another interesting finding. The locationManager in A.m who is monitoring beacon region also receives the region leave triggered by the geo region observed in the location manager in B.m.  I give it another try to create a C.m with another locationManger to observe geo region. It does not interfere with the one in B.m. So far, this seems happen only for the case when one is monitoring beacon region, the other is monitoring geo region.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the Same Issue when i created 2 Classes (1 for Geo Fencing(CLRegion or CLCircularRegions) and 2 for Beacon REgions(CLBeaconRegions).Both are singleton Classes with property Called lManager(CLLocationManager).

initially I tried with this Conditional Check

```
if (manager == self.gpsLocationManager) {
  // Do things 
}
```

as Wilmar said. Its not working..

after deep investigation on Region Classes, i Used below condition to variate the regions .
EX :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLCircularRegion!) {

      if(region.isMemberOfClass(CLCircularRegion)){
    // Do things. here 
 }
}
```

Its working for me.

Cheers :p

Answer (score 0):

In your A.m and B.m you can check if the locationManager that is responding is the locationManager you are interested in, and react accordingly. I would however try and stick to a single locationManager as mentioned by davidgyoung.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (manager == self.gpsLocationManager) {
        // do things
    }
    else {
        // this is another location manager which I am not interested in
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the delegate just use the correct instance anyway? Surely your solution would only work if the same delegate was used for multiple location manager instances?

Comment: @trojanfoe Agree with what you say. Merely made the suggestion for the check as we don't have the full context of the code.

Comment: this was what I tried in the first place and it did not solve the problem